# CSS background image not visible

Tags: css, background-image, css-sprites

I have some problems with my css background-image property. I checked and the image is in the right folder. When i put it in another page for testing it works and i see it. But when i put it in the page that i want then it doesn't work thought the test page is in the same folder. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(img/sprite_menu.png) top left no-repeat;
}
#wrapper:hover{
    background-position:0 -30px; 
}
```

What is wrong with my code? why can't i see it?

**Edit:**
The browser says that it cannot load the image when i use inspect element tool.

Comment: its gotta be something with the folder structure, because nothing looks wrong here. Double check where the image and file are relative to each other. little annoyances like this are very common. Is the test page in the same folder as the image, or your other page?

Comment: @abdul yes the other page is in the same folder . the image is in the img folder. What should i change for it to work?

Comment: Just to confirm the code works: http://jsfiddle.net/jds9rc86/

Comment: @BlaiseM. check the answer by Tal Shaked, I think you're missing quotes

Comment: @AbdulAhmad my jsfiddle works without quotes :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
background: url("/img/sprite_menu.png") top left no-repeat;
```

Comment: can't believe I didn't spot that.

Comment: I just included test.html to make it simpler and to work

Answer (score 1):

imagine your folder structure is like this:

|mysite| -- |assets|-- |img|--|sprite_menu.png|
-------------------------- |css|--|style.css|

then you have to tell your url that it has to go back to assets and then goes to img/sprite_menu.png

So your code should be:

```
background: url(../img/sprite_menu.png) top left no-repeat;
```

Comment: But the page with html code is in assets folder. So it should go to img and get the image without going back again. okay

Comment: Strange.. I built a test-site and it worked for me. Maybe you setup a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try adding a / to the image root. Starting the search from the main root folder can help you fix it.

```
#wrapper{
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(/img/sprite_menu.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```

so presuming the folder structure looks like:

```
html/index.html
html/img/sprite-menu.jpg
```